# If I have 4 Chkbxs, if multiple are true how do i get a form txtbx to equal the chkbx values?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, simplify

I feel that my code explains what I want, better than my English.

If nothing is checked I need it to equal whatever is written in there. If SUDAS is true I want "DAS DEGD" to be added to the Startup.value. If SUDAS & SUCM is true I want the start up value to say "DAS DEGD, CM DEGD". I am so lost! This is what I originally had:

```
If SUEW.Value = True And SUDAS.Value = False And SUCM.Value = False And SURDR.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD"
    
ElseIf SUDAS.Value = True And SUEW.Value = False And SUCM.Value = False And SURDR.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "DAS DEGD"
   
ElseIf SUCM.Value = True And SUEW.Value = False And SUDAS.Value = False And SURDR.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "CM DEGD"
    
ElseIf SURDR.Value = True And SUDAS.Value = False And SUCM.Value = False And SUEW.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "RADAR DEGD"
    
'All
ElseIf SUDAS.Value And SUEW.Value And SUCM.Value And SURDR = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, DAS DEGD, CM DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
    
'3 Checks
ElseIf SUEW.Value = True And SUDAS.Value = True And SURDR.Value = True And SUCM.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, DAS DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
  
ElseIf SUEW.Value = True And SUCM.Value = True And SURDR.Value = True And SUDAS.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, CM DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
    
ElseIf SUDAS.Value = True And SUCM.Value = True And SURDR.Value = True And SUEW.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "DAS DEGD, CM DEGD, RADAR DEGD"

ElseIf SUEW.Value = True And SUDAS.Value = True And SUCM.Value = True And SURDR.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, DAS DEGD, CM DEGD"

'2 Checks
ElseIf SUDAS.Value And SUEW.Value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, DAS DEGD"
  
ElseIf SUEW.Value And SUCM.Value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, CM DEGD"
    
ElseIf SUDAS.Value And SUCM.Value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "DAS DEGD, CM DEGD"

ElseIf SURDR.Value And SUEW.Value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
  
ElseIf SURDR.Value And SUCM.Value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "CM DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
    
ElseIf SUDAS.Value And SURDR.Value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "DAS DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
  
'False
ElseIf SUEW.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = ""
    
ElseIf SUDAS.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = ""
    
ElseIf SUCM.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = ""

ElseIf SURDR.Value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = ""
    
End If
```

This was my attempt to simplify:

```
Dim SUChkBx As String

SUChkBx = "" 

If SUDAS.Value = True Then
    SUChkBx = SUChkBx + " DAS DEGD"
If SUEW.Value = True Then
    SUChkBx = SUChkBx + " EW DEGD"
If SUCM.Value = True Then
    SUChkBx = SUChkBx + " CM DEGD"
If SURDR.Value = True Then
    SUChkBx = SUChkBx + " RADAR DEGD"
    
StartUp.Value = SUChkBx

End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest your `If`'s

```vb
Dim SUChkBx As String

SUChkBx = "" 

If SUDAS.Value = True Then SUChkBx = SUChkBx & ", DAS DEGD"
If SUEW.Value = True Then SUChkBx = SUChkBx & ", EW DEGD"
If SUCM.Value = True Then SUChkBx = SUChkBx & ", CM DEGD"
If SURDR.Value = True Then SUChkBx = SUChkBx & ", RADAR DEGD"

'Trim off any starting `, `
If Len(SUChkBx) > 0 Then SUChkBx = Right(SUChkBx, Len(SUChkBx)-2)
    
StartUp.Value = SUChkBx
```

In VBA `&` is the preferred way to concatenate: using `+` can cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the why, however it didnt work. The StartUp.Value (Form TxtBx) didn't show any text when a chkbx was clicked. there was no error msg either. Was using a string the right method of doing this?

Comment: How are you triggering this code?

Comment: Its a checkbox so, by clicking it? Did that answer your question?

Comment: So you have that code in the click event for all 4 checkboxes?

Comment: Yes! I had the above code match for all 4 of the checkboxes under the "click" command.

Comment: Then it should work, but you don't need all that code in each checkbox click event - put it in a separate sub and just call it from each checkbox.