# How do I use a module in a code in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba, module

I would like to use a module in my code:

```
Private Sub SUEW_Click()

Call Module1

End Sub
```

Module1 is supposed to add text to a txtbx in a form if the chkbx is selected (4 total Chkbx). Module1 contains the following code:

```
Private Sub Module1()

If SUNSTR.Value = True Then SUEW.Value , SUDAS.Value, SUCM.Value, SURDR.Value = False

'1 Checks
If SUEW.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD"
If SUDAS.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "DAS DEGD"
If SUCM.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "CM DEGD"
If SURDR.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "RADAR DEGD"
    
'All
If SUDAS.Value And SUEW.Value And SUCM.Value And SURDR = True Then StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, DAS DEGD, CM DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
    
'3 Checks
If SUEW.Value And SUDAS.Value And SURDR.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, DAS DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
If SUEW.Value And SUCM.Value And SURDR.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, CM DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
If SUDAS.Value And SUCM.Value And SURDR.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "DAS DEGD, CM DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
If SUEW.Value And SUDAS.Value And SUCM.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, DAS DEGD, CM DEGD"

'2 Checks
If SUDAS.Value And SUEW.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, DAS DEGD"
If SUEW.Value And SUCM.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, CM DEGD"
If SUDAS.Value And SUCM.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "DAS DEGD, CM DEGD"
If SURDR.Value And SUEW.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "EW DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
If SURDR.Value And SUCM.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "CM DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
If SUDAS.Value And SURDR.Value = True Then StartUp.Value = "DAS DEGD, RADAR DEGD"
  
'False
If SUEW.Value = False Then StartUp.Value = ""
If SUDAS.Value = False Then StartUp.Value = ""
If SUCM.Value = False Then StartUp.Value = ""
If SURDR.Value = False Then StartUp.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Im not very familiar with modules. I'm not sure if this the right way to use it or not, but no txt pops up in my text bx (Startup.value). Please help! TIA!

Comment: Why is the `Sub` private? Do you realize what that does? [You can look it up here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sub-statement)

Comment: Those last 4 lines will clear `StartUp` if *any* of the four checkboxes is unchecked.  Also this is not valid VBA - `If SUNSTR.Value = True Then SUEW.Value , SUDAS.Value, SUCM.Value, SURDR.Value = False`

Answer (score 0):

Going backwards a bit from your previous post on this - [If I have 4 Chkbxs, if multiple are true how do i get a form txtbx to equal the chkbx values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73113812/478884) ...

You don't need all of the logic in the event handler for each of the four checkboxes - you can put it in one place and just call it from each of the evet handlers. In this case the logic is in `RunCheck`: that Sub looks at each of the checkboxes in turn, and - depending on whether they're checked or not - builds up a string to be placed into `StartUp`.

This should work fine:

```vb
Private Sub SUEW_Click()
    RunCheck
End Sub
'add 3 more Subs for the other checkboxes


Sub RunCheck()
    Dim SUChkBx As String
    SUChkBx = "" 
    BuildIt SUChkBx, SUDAS, "DAS DEGD"
    BuildIt SUChkBx, SUEW, "EW DEGD"
    BuildIt SUChkBx, SUCM, "CM DEGD"
    BuildIt SUChkBx, SURDR, "RADAR DEGD"
    StartUp.Value = SUChkBx
End Sub

' building a comma-delimited list
Sub BuildIt(ByRef txt as string, cb As Object, v As String)
    If cb.Value = True Then 
        txt = txt & IIf(Len(txt) > 0, ", ", "") & v
    End If
End Sub
```

`BuildIt` is just a "helper" method which factors out some logic which might otherwise be repeated in `RunCheck`.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you for answering both of my questions. I'm still pretty new to a lot of this. Would you mind explaining the `RunCheck Sub`  section and the last part `BuildIt Sub`. I understand that might be a lot, if it is, its ok! I think I get the gist.

Comment: I'm getting a compile error: Expected variable or procedure, not module, for the private SUEW Sub

Comment: Did you rename any of your code modules?

Comment: I named it `RunCheck` like in the code you provided. Should I have left it as Module1?

Comment: You shouldn’t give your modules the same name as any sub\function